# Is there any reason why GD would compress my resized image in this situation

Tags: php, image-processing, compression, gd, jpeg

I have a process where I'm taking a JPG and resizing it.

My intention is to not apply any additional compression and simply modify the dimensions, however, after the code runs the image is of smaller Kb than I expect it to be (and of worse quality).

I'm curious if there's something I'm doing wrong (I'm new to GD/Imagemagick) and if there's some other step I need to be employing to preserve the quality.

Here's my code:

```
$src = imagecreatefromjpeg($originalLocation);
$dst = imagecreatetruecolor($destinationWidth, $destinationHeight);
list($oWidth, $oHeight, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($originalLocation);
imagecopyresampled($dst, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0,$destinationWidth,$destinationHeight,$oWidth,$oHeight);
imagejpeg($dst, $destinationLocation, 100 );
```

The source image is 1024x600 and ~450k
The resulting image is 640x375 but only ~30k

The only place in the code where I am seemingly in control of the compression is in the imagejpeg call where I am passing 100.  Why is an image that's >50% the size of the original shrinking to <%10 file size?

[EDIT]
added example files:
[image: BEFORE]
[image: AFTER]

TIA

Comment: Technically it's not `>50%` of the size - it's about 240k pixels compared to an original ~614k pixels.

Comment: What does the 30k image look like?

Comment: Have you looked at the destination file to see what it looks like? 30k is really tiny for a 640x375 image at high quality. Maybe the dimensions aren't what you think they are.

Comment: Do you have the ability to test on a different host?  I've run into plenty of inconsistencies with different GD versions and OSs.  It'd be nice to rule that out...

Comment: @Amber, I hear you, but I'm expecting the final file to have a similar ratio... currently it's dramatically different.

Comment: @MarkRansom, yeah, the files are definitely scaling correctly (they're proportional and contain the same image), I agree 30k is much smaller than what I expect and/or want for that size, but I'm stumped as to why it's compressing!

Comment: @CookieOfFortune, it looks exactly as I expect it to look, except that it's more pixelated owing to the additional (unwanted) compression

Comment: How are you verifying the pixel dimensions of the final file? Pixelated might mean it's being expanded in the browser. It would help if you could post sample images before and after.

Comment: From the manual: "**Note**: There is a problem due to palette image limitations (255+1 colors). Resampling or filtering an image commonly needs more colors than 255, a kind of approximation is used to calculate the new resampled pixel and its color. With a palette image we try to allocate a new color, if that failed, we choose the closest (in theory) computed color. This is not always the closest visual color."  Quantizing a 24-bit jpeg to an 8 bit palette would do pretty much what you describe

Comment: @TerryE, I'm not sure what to make of that. I have more than 255 colors in the original.  What alternative are they proposing to resample? Am I using the wrong method?

Comment: IIRC, jpeg encoding does a tiled discrete costine transform, thesholdss low freq elts to 0 and then does runlength and huffman encoding of the stream.  This is lossy, and dropping the scale from 24 bits to an effective 8 chucks out a lot of info.  The docs suggest that you maintain the true palette.  I've only used this lib for thumbnail generation, but what do the discussions on the PHP user comments say?

Comment: Huummm, this is one that I'm going to have to research further for my own interest, so +1 to the Q :)

Comment: Thanks TerryE, please chime back if you discover anything illuminating! I'm going to try using ImageMagick instead, and seeing if that works more predictably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ImageMagik totally solved the problem, so, I'm just using that.

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks OK, but it's clear that the quality setting is being ignored. Even though [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php) states you can use a quality setting up to 100, I'd try 99 to see if it makes a difference.